# Unable to install software or update the system after half installed java

Tags: java, uninstall, error-handling

Please help solve 'oracle-java7-installer' missing. Error below

```
dpkg: warning: files list file for package !['oracle-java7-installer' missing;][1] 
assuming package has no files currently installed (Reading database ... 302933 files and directories currently installed.) Removing linux-image-extra-3.8.0-19-generic ... /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-image-extra-3.8.0-19-generic.postrm: 6: /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-image-extra-3.8.0-19-generic.postrm: Syntax error: ")" 
unexpected dpkg: error processing linux-image-extra-3.8.0-19-generic (--remove):  subprocess installed post-removal script returned error exit status 2 
Errors were encountered while processing:  linux-image-extra-3.8.0-19-generic 
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1) A package failed to install.  Trying to recover:
```

Comment: unable to install software or update the system after half installed java

Comment: The error codes http://paste.ubuntu.com/5893213/

Comment: The paste you posted, is not of current question, it can't be added to this question.

Comment: but the problem is same

Comment: Hi, please do `sudo apt-get install --reinstall oracle-java7-installer` and post what happens.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Projjol for the solution.

He said,

You have a package that was not installed correctly or is broken. You have to remove linux-image-extra-3.8.0-19-generic.

I would suggest that you use the following code: `gksudo nautilus /var/lib/dpkg/info` Now find all files starting with names `linux-headers-3.8.0-19` and delete them. Then:

```
sudo apt-get -f install

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get dist-upgrade

sudo apt-get install linux
```

Your system should work fine then.